# wpf Window_stateChange cant get width chance to register

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
    private void SizeChangedEventHandler(Object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        channelTabs.Width = (Convert.ToInt32(this.Width) - 20) / 2;
        dsMainScrollView.Width = (Convert.ToInt32(this.Width) - 20) / 2;
    }

    private void Window_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        channelTabs.Width = (Convert.ToInt32(this.ActualWidth) - 20) / 2;
        dsMainScrollView.Width = (Convert.ToInt32(this.ActualWidth) - 20) / 2;
    }
```

these two functions update two log views, which are supposed to take the left and right half od the window respectively. the top one is very slow, but it actually functions. the bottom one is the issue, because i cant seem to get it to register when the screen is maximized. i have tried:
A) using actual width vs just width
B) using a switch to assure that it knows window state is maximized
C) using the screen width instead of the windows width

but something still is not registering and the width of the two objects is not changing

i am operating in .net 3.5 to allow compatibility on windows XP systems that my company uses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to replace all the code that perform manual size calculation with the standard [WPF Grid layout container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), to create two-column layout for you log-views in declarative manner:

```
<Grid Margin="20">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" x:Name="logView1"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="2" x:Name="logView2"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you, not only did that solve the problem but now i can apply column definitions to other situations.